# Vue.js v-for not working in the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have a Vue.js application. I get a list via ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: this.base_info.url + 'getavailability?token=' + this.token,
    data: this.search_info,
    success: function (list) {
        this.results = list;
        console.log(list);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

And here is the result:

```
{
  "success": "true",
  "error": "false",
  "items": [
    {
      "relation_id": "9961",
      "recommendation_id": "1",
      "combination_id": "3",
      "total_fare": "5530000",
      "quantity_adult": "1",
      "totalfare_adult": "5,530,000",
      "quantity_child": "0",
      "totalfare_child": "0",
      "quantity_infant": "0",
      "totalfare_infant": "0",
      "airlines_name": "Qatar Airways",
      "airline_logo": "QR"
    },
    {
      "relation_id": "9962",
      "recommendation_id": "1",
      "combination_id": "4",
      "total_fare": "5530000",
      "quantity_adult": "1",
      "totalfare_adult": "5,530,000",
      "quantity_child": "0",
      "totalfare_child": "0",
      "quantity_infant": "0",
      "totalfare_infant": "0",
      "airlines_name": "Qatar Airways",
      "airline_logo": "QR"
    },
  ]
}
```

When I loop through the result via Vue js, it outputs and empty row in my table.

```
<div v-for="item in results.items">
     <span class="big db">{{item.total_fare}}</span>
</div>
```

I don't know which part has problems.

Comment: The console.log does return the result that you have posted? Have you tried assigning items as a separate variable (that's obviously not a solution but we're just looking for something)? Have you tried predefining the object without any AJAX requests? Do that.

Comment: yes, console log returns the results, but the new fields are not pre-defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your success handler attach the items like

```
this.$set('results.items', list);
```

This might force the digest cycle and in case results.items was not originally declared in your data, they will be evaluated.

Comment: You don't have to use `$set` unless the data isn't initialized properly, which it should be. If it's set properly `this.results.items = list` would work. I'd definitely suggest to initialize the data properly over `$set`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that this within your ajax enclosure does not equate to your Vue js instance. 
To solve the issue you can do the following just before your ajax call, assign this to a variable

```
    var vm = this;

     $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: this.base_info.url + 'getavailability?token=' + this.token,

    data: this.search_info,
    success: function (list) {
        const json = JSON.parse(list) as DataType_Of_Results;
        vm.results = json;
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

1. Define a class that encapsulates the properties returned

   ```
   class result{
      relation_id: string,
     recommendation_id: string,
     combination_id: string,
     total_fare: string,
     quantity_adult: string,
     totalfare_adult: string,
     quantity_child: string,
     totalfare_child: string,
     quantity_infant: string,
     totalfare_infant: string,
     airlines_name: string,
     airline_logo: string

     }
   ```

In Data section on you Vue Instance

```
 data:{
    result: new Array<result>()
    },
    method:{
      getresult: function(){


    var vm = this;

     $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: this.base_info.url + 'getavailability?token=' + this.token,

    data: this.search_info,
    success: function (list) {
        const jsonResult = JSON.parse(list) as Array<result>;
        vm.results = jsonResult;
    }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure 'results' is defined in the data section of your Vue instance and you will also have to make sure this 'results' defined is of same data type as that of the data returned by 'list'.

Secondly, I think its better to console log 'this.results' rather  than 'list' since its  'this.results' you are looping through and not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have an extra , after the last entry

```
{
  "relation_id": "9962",
  "recommendation_id": "1",
  "combination_id": "4",
  "total_fare": "5530000",
  "quantity_adult": "1",
  "totalfare_adult": "5,530,000",
  "quantity_child": "0",
  "totalfare_child": "0",
  "quantity_infant": "0",
  "totalfare_infant": "0",
  "airlines_name": "Qatar Airways",
  "airline_logo": "QR"
},
```

]

which results in an empty row

Answer (score 0):

`"this"` in your success callback does not refer to the vue Instance, it refers to jquery. you should do

```
var vueInstance = this;
  $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: this.base_info.url + 'getavailability?token=' + this.token,
  data: this.search_info,
  success: function (list) {
      vueInstance.results = list;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute the ajax request when the component is installed, for that use the function `created () {ajax ...}` or `mounted () {ajax ...}` the data will be before the start `v-for`of the`div`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply retrieve your availability array in a Vuex prop, then bind it as computed prop in your component; that will make the property reactive and as soon as the api call succeeded you will have the data in the template too.

so, in actions.js

```
async getAvailabilityArray ({commit}) {
  try {
    const data = await apiService.post('getavailability', {token: 'foo', etc})
    commit('mutateAvailabilityArray', data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

in component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in results.items">
      <span class="big db">{{item.total_fare}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['availabilityArray']
    }
  }
</script>
```

Ooor if not using Vuex, use AsyncComputed prop ( `yarn add vue-async-computed` )

```
 <template>
   <div> {{availabilityArray}} </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 export default {
   asyncComputed: {
     async availabilityArray() {
       return await promiseLand()
     }
   },
   methods: {
     promiseLand() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         apiService.post('getavailability', {token: 'foo', etc})
           .then(res => {
             resolve(res)
           }).catch(err => reject(err))
       })
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
```